# How to find if there is any emotion attached with a sentence in NLP?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

For example, if I have the sentence:
"I went there yesterday."- It has no emotion or no emotion word.
But this sentence:
"I was surprised by that" - It has certain emotion in word surprise.

Can we do this using any NLTK library?

Answer (score 0):

If it is just to check the sentiments, you can use the Textblob library. Check following link: https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html#sentiment-analysis

If there is specific requirement, elaborate the what do you want to achieve. Like, what is the scenario where you want to implement NLTK (or any other library).